# Is there a usecase for overriding __hash__?

Tags: python-3.x, hash, magic-function

In Python3 any class will have a default `__hash__` which calculates a hash based on the member variables. I can set it (explicitly or implicitly) to None in order make the class non-hashable, which certainly has some usecases.

But are there reasons to override `__hash__`?

I couldn't find one.

Comment: One things that comes to my mind is to speed up by precomputing hash values and using `__hash__` to retrieve these precomputed values.

Comment: If your class is based on a generally unhashable type (maybe list?),  but you know the class instance can be defined in some unique way, defining your own `__hash__` would let you express that.

Comment: @AndrejKesely some (not very elaborated) tests showed no measurable difference. But maybe for classes with data that needs long to compare? What kind of data would that be? Huge strings?

Comment: @StephenRauch: Haven't thought about that one.

Comment: @steffen Yes, huge strings would by my first target. Or if your data is accessed dynamically from network/database. Or If you have your data in some unhashable data-structure (e.g. `set()`, but `frozenset()` is hashable)...

Comment: @AndrejKesely data over the network is a good point as well. When data is in mutable types, it is ignored in the default hash as it seems. And that is probably what you wanted in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Any time you override `__eq__`, and also want to be able to use the object as the key in a set or dict. This is especially common in value types, or cases where your objects represent real world entities.

`__hash__` does not hash member variables at all. For an object without `__hash__` or `__eq__` defined, it returns some value based on its internal pointer. If `__eq__` *is* defined, then invoking the method will cause a TypeError.work

Consider this simple case where that default `__eq__` and `__hash__` behavior isn't great:

```
import getpass

class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def currentUser():
   return User(getpass.getuser())

me = currentUser()

passwords = {}
passwords[me] = "sw0rdfish";
```

This has some weird behavior: `me == currentUser()` is false, and `passwords[currentUser()]` throws a KeyError. So to try to fix it, we define an `__eq__`:

```
def __eq__(self, other): 
    return self.name == other.name
```

Now the `me == currentUser()` is true, but trying to assign the password throws a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'User'`.  Now we've gotten to the point where we want to override `__hash__`:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.name)
```

And now it behaves like you'd expect any other such object to behave when you use it as a key.